# how to fetch new messages without overloading server in php?

Tags: chat

which technology is being used in Google or Facebook chat applications to fetch new messages from server without overloading server with continuous servers queries using Ajax calls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook and Gmail might be using Real time messaging protocol for instant messaging.
Please refer this page to read more about RTMP
wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol

Comment: @eon "RTMP (except RTMFP) is a TCP-based protocol which maintains persistent connections and allows low-latency communication... the RTMP encapsulates MP3 or AAC audio and FLV1 video multimedia streams, and can make remote procedure calls (RPCs)...", source: wikipedia.org, so for a webchat they shall use a lighter protocol! In addition, "RTMP is now available as an open specification to create products and technology that enable delivery of video, audio, and data in the open AMF, SWF, FLV, and F4V formats...", source: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html